# NGINX prevent caching certain locations, while having FCGI

Tags: laravel, nginx, caching, fastcgi

I have a Laravel application. Here is my NGINX config file:

```
server {                                                                                                                                                                          
     # Log files for Debugging
     access_log /var/log/nginx/access-test.log;
     error_log /var/log/nginx/access-test.log;                                                     

     # Webroot Directory for Laravel project                         
     root /var/www/html/deploy/website/current/public;             
     index index.php index.html index.htm;

     # Your Domain Name
     server_name test.example.com;

    location / {                                      
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }                                    

     # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx                    
     location ~ \.php$ {                  
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;      
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
             include fastcgi_params;
     }          

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot                      
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I want to prevent any kind of caching in certain locations, say '/submit/*'.

I tried adding this above `location /`:

```
    location ~ /submit {
             expires -1;
             add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0' always;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

I also added a middleware to my Laravel app, to `/submit` sub-paths that appends `Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0` and `Expires: <one day ago>` and `Pragma: no-cache` to response.

What I see in browser is that `Expires` and `Pragma` headers are set, but `Cache-Control` is not what I specified, and is being set to `max-age=31536000`.

I suspect something in NGINX is overwriting that header, but I can't seem to find it by reading docs or googling.

Any help or clue is appreciated.

BTW, I test the page in Firefox, while having inspector open, and having `Disable cache` ticked in Network tab. So I always see fresh headers from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally added following location block:

```
location ~ /submit {
         expires -1;
         add_trailer 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0' always;
             fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
             fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
             fastcgi_index index.php;
             fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
             include fastcgi_params;
}
```

It now works as expected.

The only problem is now duplication, which can be solved by having `fcgi` commands in a separate file and `include`ing it in both locations.

I'm not so pleased with my current solution, so I'm still open to new or better ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `add_header` inside a location that is being proxied. By the time the response headers are being calculated, nginx is in a different location block. And that's how the `add_header` works.

You can use `add_trailer` ([docs here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_trailer)), that should do the trick for your use case

Comment: I tried adding `add_trailer` to `location ~ /submit`, and it seems it is not working.

Comment: I mean I replaced `add_header` with `add_trailer`. Still seeing `max-age: <number>` in inspector tab.

Comment: I'm sorry, for some reason, this worked for me in the past. Not sure what's going on. For your specific use-case, i would just return the correct header from the backend, not from nginx (if we are talking about cache). For other headers, i would use a map: 
`map $request_uri $some_var {
  default "1";
  ~^/test(.*) "2";
}`

Then, in the proxy_pass location, you can `fastcgi_hide_header My-Header; add_header My-Header $some_var`. Let me know once you read this, as i would rater delete this bad answer, or edit it with what i just said here.

Comment: I already tried sending headers from backend without luck. NGINX ignores `Cache-Control` header sent from backend, but keeps other ones. The thing about using a map is that I don't want to replace default functionality, and using a map makes me provide a default one. See my other answer for my current solution. Thanks for the advice on `add_trailer` anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. I saw your response, and it makes sense. And yes, you can def `include` the common parts and you'll be good. Also, i tested on a Laravel app, and was able to send Cache-Control from the backend with no issues. I did something like return `response(...)->header('Cache-Control', 'public');`